# Unable to pass Data to my second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, segue

When trying to pass data that has been called from CoreData, the error returned shows Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The debugger reads

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

However, when I add print statements before assigning my variables to the textfields, the variables print out correctly. I am beyond lost. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editInventoryItem") as! AddInventoryItemVC
          var inventoryItemName: String = ""
          var inventoryItemStock: Double = 0.0
          var inventoryItemPG: Double = 0.0
          var inventoryItemVG: Double = 0.0
          let itemName = flavors[indexPath.row]

          let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
          let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
          let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Inventory")

          request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "inventoryItemName ==%@", itemName)
          if let result = try? context.fetch(request) {
              for object in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                  inventoryItemName = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemName") as! String
                  inventoryItemStock = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemStock") as! Double
                  inventoryItemPG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemPGPercent") as! Double
                  inventoryItemVG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemVGPercent") as! Double
              }
          } else {

          }

          myVC.itemName.text = inventoryItemName
          myVC.itemStock.text = "\(inventoryItemStock)"
          myVC.itemPG.text = "\(inventoryItemPG)"
          myVC.itemVG.text = "\(inventoryItemVG)"

          performSegue(withIdentifier: "editInventoryItem", sender: "")
      }
```

EDIT:
After applying Rinki's suggestions, Xcode gave me the following corrections and, upon running, still returns the same errors.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let itemName = flavors[indexPath.row]

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Inventory")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "inventoryItemName ==%@", itemName)
    if let result = try? context.fetch(request) {
        for object in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            inventoryItemName = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemName") as! String
            inventoryItemStock = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemStock") as! Double
            inventoryItemPG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemPGPercent") as! Double
            inventoryItemVG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemVGPercent") as! Double
        }
    } else {

    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editInventoryItem", sender: "")
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editInventoryItem" {
        let myVC = segue.destination as! AddInventoryItemVC
        myVC.itemName.text = inventoryItemName
        myVC.itemStock.text = "\(inventoryItemStock)"
        myVC.itemPG.text = "\(inventoryItemPG)"
        myVC.itemVG.text = "\(inventoryItemVG)"
    }
}
```

UPDATE: After some printing, it now makes sense why the errors are returning. `prepareForSegue()` is being called before `didSelectRow`, so the value is currently nil, but I have no clue how to call the `didSelectRow` before `prepareForSegue()` is called.

EDIT: After doing some research and implementing a Singleton, I've fixed the issue. I've added an `identifier` variable in the Singleton, changing the variable to `editInventoryItem` when didSelectRow is called. On the second VC, I set up a simple if statement that compares `identifier` to `editInventoryItem` and fills the textfields in question.

Thank you all for all of your help. One error down, probably 5,000,000 to go! :D

Comment: How are your initializing the variables your are assigning your data too? There's a chance that you do not have a strong reference to the receiving properties and in turn are losing that data. I know when digging into child/parent context, passing and assigning the child context, along with the data, to the receiving class is required—do to a weak reference on child contexts.

Comment: Now that they are used in two separate functions, I have moved them to the beginning of the class, making them available to both functions.

Comment: put breakpoint and check at which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Rinki check my update. The value is nil because the `prepare()` is being called before the `didSelectRow`. Though, I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, but I have no idea what to replace `UIStoryboardSegue` with when calling the `prepare()` function.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value -> this comes when you miss ? or ! for your variable. Recheck properly.

Comment: `myVC.itemName.text = inventoryItemName!` causes an error that tells me to delete the "!"

Comment: Why don't you try with Singleton shared instance? For me, it's easier to pass data between classes, in this case, viewControllers with shared instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with core data, but your use of segues.  The method performSegue is create a new viewController from the storyboard.  `myVC` that was created from `instantiateViewController` is discarded at the end of the function.  Instead use `prepareForSegue:sender:` to add the values to the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

prepareForSegue() method will be called after calling performSegue:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "editInventoryItem", sender: nil)
```

Here you can send your data from SourceViewController to Destination View Controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if(segue.identifier == "editInventoryItem") {
        let myVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController
        myVC.itemName.text = inventoryItemName
      myVC.itemStock.text = "\(inventoryItemStock)"
      myVC.itemPG.text = "\(inventoryItemPG)"
      myVC.itemVG.text = "\(inventoryItemVG)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first ViewController, my code is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let itemName = flavors[indexPath.row]

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Inventory")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "inventoryItemName ==%@", itemName)
    if let result = try? context.fetch(request) {
        for object in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            Singleton.sharedInstance.itemName = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemName") as! String
            Singleton.sharedInstance.itemStock = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemStock") as! Double
            Singleton.sharedInstance.itemPG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemPGPercent") as! Double
            Singleton.sharedInstance.itemVG = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemVGPercent") as! Double
        }
    } else {

    }
    Singleton.sharedInstance.identifier = "editInventoryItem"
}
```

My Singleton:

```
struct Singleton {
    static var sharedInstance = Singleton()

    var identifier = ""
    var itemName = ""
    var itemStock = 0.0
    var itemVG = 0.0
    var itemPG = 0.0
}
```

On the first ViewController, my implementing code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(Singleton.sharedInstance.identifier)
    print(Singleton.sharedInstance.itemName)

    if Singleton.sharedInstance.identifier == "editInventoryItem" {
        nicotineSwitch.isEnabled = false
        VGSwitch.isEnabled = false
        PGSwitch.isEnabled = false

        itemName.text = Singleton.sharedInstance.itemName
        itemStock.text = "\(Singleton.sharedInstance.itemStock)"
        itemPG.text = "\(Singleton.sharedInstance.itemPG)"
        itemVG.text = "\(Singleton.sharedInstance.itemVG)"
        Singleton.sharedInstance.identifier = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with `Singleton shared instance`.

Create a new Swift file of type NSObject

YourAppState.swift

```
    class YourAppState : NSObject {
        class var sharedInstance: YourAppState {
          struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: YourAppState? = nil
          }

          dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = YourAppState()
          }

         return Static.instance!

        }
    }
```

And with this you can do the following:

Create a new variable inside the shared instance file,

`var inventoryItemName = ""`

And before going to next VC or performing segue,
give the value to `inventoryItemName = object.value(forKey: "inventoryItemName") as! String`. In the destination VC class pass the value like this.

`self.itemName.text = YourAppState.sharedInstance().inventoryItemName`

Just make sure you add the value before performing a segue.

Hope it helps, cheers!